# Jupyter labextension Fail to build, error package.json cannot be found

Tags: node.js, anaconda, jupyter-lab

I am having issue trying to 'jupyter labextension build'. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated please.

here is the **jupyter labextension list**

```
JupyterLab v3.0.14
C:\Users\xxxx.conda\envs\jz\share\jupyter\labextensions
@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager v3.0.0 enabled ok (python, jupyterlab_widgets)
@voila-dashboards/jupyterlab-preview v2.0.2 enabled ok (python, voila)

Other labextensions (built into JupyterLab)
app dir: C:\Users\xxxx.conda\envs\jz\share\jupyter\lab
jupyterlab-plotly v4.14.3 enabled ok
plotlywidget v4.14.3 enabled ok
```

as you can see, everything pretty much the most up to date and in 'sync'.

**the log** looks this:

```
Building extension in C:\Users\xxxxx
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\xxxxx.conda\envs\jz\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\debuglog.py", line 47, in debug_logging
yield

File "C:\Users\xxxxx.conda\envs\jz\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\labextensions.py", line 128, in start
ans = self.run_task()

File "C:\Users\xxxxx.conda\envs\jz\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\labextensions.py", line 227, in run_task
build_labextension(self.extra_args[0], logger=self.log, development=self.development, static_url=self.static_url or None, source_map = self.source_map,

File "C:\Users\xxxxx.conda\envs\jz\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\federated_labextensions.py", line 168, in build_labextension
builder = _ensure_builder(ext_path, core_path)

File "C:\Users\xxxxx.conda\envs\jz\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\federated_labextensions.py", line 226, in _ensure_builder
with open(osp.join(ext_path, 'package.json')) as fid:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\xxxxx\package.json'

Exiting application: lab
```

Comment: You redacted too much of the path in `'C:\Users\xxxxx\package.json'` to be able to understand **which** `package.json` is causing the issue. Please add back the missing details.

Comment: hi @krassowski, thanks for the reply.  the xxxxx in 'C:\Users\xxxxx\package.json', is the exactly my user name. There are no further directory.  So, the above is simply: 'C:\Users\my_user_name\package.json',

Comment: This is very strange. Is would indicate that your installation thinks that there is an extension in your home directory (which it obviously is not)